# Plotting bar-plot/clustered column charts in R from csv file using ggplo2

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I am planning to plot a **bar-plot/clustered column chart** for time vs revenue with **trend-line** connecting each bars on top. Starting from year 1981 to 1988.

I have used this code to read the csv : `read.csv(file_location/Revenue.csv",header = T, sep=",", dec = ".")`

for the plotting : `pl <- ggplot(data,aes(x=ï..Year))`

and then : `pl + geom_bar(color='red',fill='blue')`.

Unfortunately, [i end up with something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv084.png). Whereas, [i'd prefer something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b1G4.png). 
I used only *ggplot2* library in this case, should i use  *tidyr, diplyr* additionally ? Am i mistaking between continuous and discrete variables. Any advice regarding aesthetic modification to beautify it or solutions regarding this would be really appreciated as i am still in the basics of ggplot and data visualizations.

I have added the fine in case if you want to check it : [Revenue.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OiiK4n6Ns2VmYkIeRpgO5JSj_WqK36xt/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the documentation here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html) form some information, but the big change you should make is to use `geom_col` in place of `geom_bar`.  Your current call specifies an `x=` aesthetic (what should be the x axis), but not the `y=` aesthetic (what should be the y axis).  `geom_bar` indicates the number of cases/observations at each x value by default, whereas `geom_col` is used to display a bar of length y at each x value... but you need a y aesthetic.

With all that being said, try this:

```
pl <- ggplot(data,aes(x=ï..Year, y=your.y.column.name)) +
    geom_col(color='red',fill='blue')
```

As for aesthetics, I might change the color scheme a bit and also the theme, but that's ind of personal preference.  My suggestion would be to at least change your color scheme for `geom_bar/col`.  The `color=` specifies the outline on the bars, and the `fill=` is the color of the bars.  Your code would give you bright blue bars with a red outline... not awesome.  I would also change the width of your bars a to be a bit skinnier by adjusting the `width=` argument from the default of 1 to something smaller.  Here is an example with a dummy dataset.  Most people (me included) would not want to download someone else's data via a link, sorry.

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    geom_col(fill='steelblue', color='black', width=0.5) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked fine for me. I customized the plot a bit with these codes : ```ggplot(data,aes(x=ï..Year, y=Amount,fill=Amount))+ geom_col() + geom_smooth(method = 'loess',se=FALSE) + theme_bw()+ scale_fill_gradient(low = '#08AEEA',high = '#2AF598')``` However i am having trouble with drawing a trend-line above the barplot, could you point me some smoothing method documentation regarding it or some solutions perhaps ? Also, numbers in my data are pretty huge and it's showing "1e+08", is there anything i can do about it so that i can have actual numbers there in the plot?

Comment: Sure: for trendline, you can try `geom_smooth`, or if you have the equation for a straight line, go for `geom_abline`.  Check documentation for either of them for more information.  As for number, probably the `scales` package will work for you.  You can use `math_format` in particular to apply to `labels=` inside a `scale_..._...` function to set the format of your numbers.  A bunch of other useful functions in that package for similar adjustments.